# recovering ubuntu in dual boot system with window 10

Tags: dual-boot

I was using windows 10 and then I did a dual boot with ubuntu 16.04 and used this as it is for months but afterward dual to some hardware problem(screen display) I gave my laptop to a service center to fix it but after getting back my system is only showing windows not ubuntu. Is there anything that we can do recover ubuntu.

Comment: likely the gave you a new computer. and ubuntu isn't on it

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Try what i answered in this similar post
https://askubuntu.com/questions/975515/keeping-ubuntu-17-10-installation-whilst-reinstalling-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

while bootloading(before showing the Windows logo), try keep pressing left shift button. if Grub is there it will load the grub. If grub loaded then you can access Ubuntu or boot with advanced options and fix broken packages. else you have to manually install grub.