# Keeping Ubuntu 17.10 Installation whilst reinstalling Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a single hard disk which has both Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10. Unfortunately, I have to go through the pain of reinstalling Windows due to some corrupt file system issue or something else that causing its performance to grind to a halt.

However, what I don't want to do is lose Ubuntu and everything that is on it. So, what I would like to do is to use my Windows bootable iso DVD disk and simply do a clean install at that location. Therefore, I on reboot I can hopefully carry on as normal.

Can someone please give me some step by step instructions?

Comment: No you are wrong and haven't read my post properly. My hard disk is already dual boot. I want to keep the partitions as they are but I don't want Windows deleting Linux or removing the dual boot.

Comment: It's OK because the linked question says *I have Ubuntu on my laptop. Now I want install Windows 7 in a **dual boot**. How can I do this? **I can't lose my Ubuntu files**, and I'm afraid that I might break GRUB.*

Comment: Windows is already there!!!

Comment: You don't need to make additional space for Windows. A Windows partition is already there, so you can reinstall Windows by overwriting the existing Windows partition.

Comment: So it is a simple process of booting the windows disk and going through the install and selecting the windows partition and installing on top of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68590/discussion-between-karel-and-andy5).

Comment: If you are currently using `UEFI` mode than there is no problem.